# How to fix issue with callable lambda serialization?

Tags: serialization, lambda, java-8, hazelcast

I'm getting this error message when trying to serialize a callable lambda which has a reference to a instance of class A. The error happens when I submit the callable to a distributed executor service in hazelcast.

```
 com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:

 java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 cannot assign instance of somepackage.A 
 to field  java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.capturingClass 
 of type java.lang.Class in instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda
```

Comment: Can you please post the code chunk ?

Comment: @newlogic looks like you need to do: `submit( (Callable & Serializable) ... ` - cast your Callable to Serializable, they are not by default.

Comment: The implementation has gotten very confused when it tries to assign `A` to `capturingClass`…

Comment: @Holger what could possibly cause this? I'm not explictly assigning A, although A is being referenced inside the lambda.

Comment: Of course, you are not. That why I said the *implementation* (of that serialization) must have gotten confused. Maybe there’s a previous error on your side that causes the structure to become corrupt, but that causal relation is so tied to the implementation details, that it is impossible to conclude from this exception to the potential cause. Or it’s just a Hazelcast bug…